# Why using "SND_SYNC" in a "QueueUserWorkItem" bad?

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++, asynchronous

Larry Osterman [writes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2009/06/25/what-s-wrong-with-this-code-part-26-a-real-world-example.aspx) about a real error found in Microsoft's code, the offending code is

```
static DWORD WINAPI _PlayBeep(__in void* pv)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(pv);
    PlaySound(L".Default"NULL, SND_SYNC | SND_ALIAS);
    return 0;
}

LRESULT WndProc(...)
{
    :
    :
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        if (!_AcceptInputKeys(wParam, lParam))
        {
            QueueUserWorkItem(_PlayBeep, NULL, 0);
        }
        break;
}
```

and Larry asks:

> Given the simplicity of the code
>   above, to get the answer right, it’s
>   not enough to say what’s wrong with
>   the code (the problem should be
>   blindingly obvious).  You also need to
>   be able to explain why this is so bad
>   (in other words, what breaks when you
>   do this).

The best answer is terse in the comments is not enough,

> David's VERY close to what's going
>   wrong - now think about the context of
>   the application.

Can someone please explain fully what's happening when this code runs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the answer page, it's got a very detailed explanation

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2009/06/29/what-s-wrong-with-this-code-part-26-the-answer.aspx

Basically, don't use `QueueUserWorkItem` for long-running work items because this can cause thread exhaustion in your process, or even deadlock in a very hard to debug way if you wait for work items to complete on a (necessarily) finite-sized thread pool.  Same goes for the .Net equivalent of this API [ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem.aspx) btw.

In this specific case, the workitem trigger ("press the down key") and the resulting thread workitem ("sound a sync beep") are very unbalanced, so that if user holds down or repeatedly hits his/her down key, the process will quickly hit fatal issues.